# Downloading text file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to download a text file with javascript. I'm using this code:

HTML:
    `<a id="save_file_local" download="data.local">Save file</a>`

Javascript:

```
save_file_local.href="data:text/plain,"+encodeURIComponent(response);
save_file_local.click();
```

Well, it works perfect with all extensions I have used.. but only with "*.local" extension, I get a file with this name: data.download
I really need to download the "*.local" file, so to change of extension is not a solution for me.
It works perfectly with Internet Explorer 10, but not with Chrome or Mozilla.

I have been searching without luck... so Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why must you use javascript? If it's a text file you should just be able to link to it with normal HTML. Plus, javascript really doesn't have access to the local file system. Also, you might find this article useful... http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

Comment: If you look at "save_file_local.href="data:text/plain,"+encodeURIComponent(response);
" he obviously is generating the file, to then download

Comment: @user1707214 Do you have access to PHP? I could give you a 3 line solution that uses PHP

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g97sT/

Comment: My problem is not the download, else the extension. @Ionică Bizău, when I click on "download", I get a file called: data.download, and I need the same file but with ".local " extension. it works for me only with IE. I'm using Windows 8

Comment: @user1707214 A file named `data.local` is downloaded on Chromium (latest version) - Ubuntu 14.04...

Answer (score -1):

From an alternate question:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>
```

Thought no way to do this completely cross browser apparently.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on your browser and on the Server.

If a Server sends the "Content-type: text/plain" the most browsers will display it. Its nothing you can change with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

As evu suggested, you could use the HTML5 `download` attribute, although it isn't [widely or consistently supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). Chrome give priority to the `download` attribute, but Firefox [gives priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to the http header `Content-Disposition`. However, if it's content you generated in JavaScript, then the `download` attribute should work.

If you've got access to the server, setting `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in your http header would be a much better solution.